# Magento 2: Plugin is not working on server while it's working fine on localhost

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, sales-order, order-email

Here I have created a plugin to stop the order mail notification for some specific payment. This plugin is working fine on my localhost but not working on server.

My **di.xml** file codes:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
        <type name="Magento\Quote\Observer\SubmitObserver">
            <plugin name="stop_order_email_for_some_payment" type="CompanyName\ModuleName\Plugin\Quote\Observer\SubmitObserver" sortOrder="0" />
        </type> 
</config>
```

And plugin file (**CompanyName/ModuleName/Plugin/Quote/Observer/SubmitObserver.php**) codes:

```
namespace CompanyName\ModuleName\Plugin\Quote\Observer;

class SubmitObserver
{
    public function beforeExecute(
        \Magento\Quote\Observer\SubmitObserver $subject,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
    ) {
        /** @var  \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order */
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $paymentCode = $order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getCode();
        $orderStatus = $order->getStatus();
        
         if($paymentCode == 'swed_m2s' || $paymentCode == 'seb_m2s' || $paymentCode == 'lhv_m2s' || $paymentCode == 'estcard_m2s' || $paymentCode == 'coop_m2s')
            {
                if($orderStatus == 'pending')
                {
                     $order->setCanSendNewEmailFlag(false);
                }
            }
       
        return [$observer];
    }
}
```

On local System both column **email_sent**, **send_email** of **sales_order** table are updating with **NULL** value according to condition and also not getting order mail notification for selected payment methods which are checked in condition.

But on server neither columns are updating nor order mail notification is stopping.

Can anyone help me with this problem, why my plugin is not working on server.

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you make plugin for observer?
You can use plugin for this : vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Email/Sender/OrderSender.php

Comment: Actually I checked this, it's working fine on my local environement that's why I used here.

Comment: Add status in log : $orderStatus

Comment: If invoice automatically created then status is different!!! Are you getting my point?

Comment: I checked and getting both values in my log file

Comment: Yes, I got your point

Comment: My order status is still in pending condition, I checked in db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you make plugin for observer? You can use plugin for this : vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Email/Sender/OrderSender.php

OR
Verify the status of order!!!
If invoice automatically created then status is different!!! Are you getting my point?

OR
Create preference

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender" type="Venodr\ModuleRewrite\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender" />
</config>
```

And Modify only this function.

```
public function send(Order $order, $forceSyncMode = false)
    {
        $payment = $order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getCode();
        $orderStatus = $order->getStatus();
        if($paymentCode == 'swed_m2s' || $paymentCode == 'seb_m2s' || $paymentCode == 'lhv_m2s' || $paymentCode == 'estcard_m2s' || $paymentCode == 'coop_m2s')
        {
            if($orderStatus == 'pending')
            {
                 return false;
            }
        }

        $order->setSendEmail($this->identityContainer->isEnabled());

        if (!$this->globalConfig->getValue('sales_email/general/async_sending') || $forceSyncMode) {
            if ($this->checkAndSend($order)) {
                $order->setEmailSent(true);
                $this->orderResource->saveAttribute($order, ['send_email', 'email_sent']);
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            $order->setEmailSent(null);
            $this->orderResource->saveAttribute($order, 'email_sent');
        }

        $this->orderResource->saveAttribute($order, 'send_email');

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain that how I use this class?

Comment: You can create preference for that!
2min iw ill update my ansere

Comment: Yes sure brother

Comment: You can also use plugin !!!!

Comment: Ok thanks brother for your effort, I will try it tomorrow and update you

Comment: Good night brother!!!

Comment: Good night to you also

Comment: Thanks brother! with some correction your solution is working fine

Comment: Welcome brother!!